# Establecer valor de movimiento arduino RAMPS

Tags: arduino

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con arduino mega, ramps y Marlin____ y quiero que cuando por consola serie le mando una A0 se mueva a un lugar concreto. Pero no quiero mandarle los datos mediante la consola serie, sino que quiero que se almacenen en el código. Es decir, en lugar de ponerle G0 X200 quiero poner A0 y que el programa sepa que es G0 X200. Y que al poner A1 el programa sepa que es G0 X220.

He intentando modificar el buffer en el que se guarda el comando recibido, de forma que si empieza por A, sea G28 Z, pero me da error de compilación.

El siguiente fragmento de código se corresponde con la función process_commads(). No copio todo el código porque son cientos de líneas, pero con esto creo que es suficiente:

```
if(code_seen('A')){
SERIAL_ECHO(cmdbuffer[bufindr]);
switch((int)code_value())
{
  case 0:

  case 1: // G1
  if(Stopped == false) {
    get_coordinates(); // For X Y Z E F
    prepare_move();
    //ClearToSend();
    return;
  }
  //break;
 }
```

}

Este fragmento de código funciona correctamente. Lo que hace es que si el comando es A0 o A1, emula el funcionamiento de G0 y G1. Ahora bien, si yo coloco la siguiente línea al inicio de la función process_comands()

```
cmdbuffer[bufindr]="G28 Z";
```

No compila, dando el siguiente error:

```
Marlin_main.cpp: In function 'void process_commands()':
Marlin_main.cpp:1065:21: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [6]' to 'char [96]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo conseguí por mi cuenta.
Si alguno tiene curiosidad, lo que hay que hacer es cambiar

```
cmdbuffer[bufindr]="G28 Z"
```

por

```
strncpy(cmdbuffer[bufindr], "G28 Z", sizeof(cmdbuffer[bufindr]));
```